# OpenCV: How to write vector<point> to image

Tags: c++, opencv

```
cv::Mat in = cv::imread("SegmentedImage.png");

// vector with all non-white point positions

std::vector<Point> nonWhiteList;

nonWhiteList.reserve(in.rows*in.cols);

// add all non-white points to the vector

for(int j=0; j< in.rows; ++j)
{

    for(int i=0; i<in.cols; ++i)
    {
        // if not white: add to the list
        if(in.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i) != cv::Vec3b(255,255,255))
        {
            nonWhiteList.push_back(cv::Point(i,j));
        }
    }
}

cv::Mat BKGR = imread("photo_booth_Cars.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR); //1529x736
```

I need to write  the `vector<Point> nonWhiteList` to image `BKGR`, How to do it?

Basically, need to remove the white background from the image and put non-white points on another background image. Researched very much on grabcut and findcontours.

I am completely new to Opencv. Thanks so much for help.

Comment: what do you want to do with 'nonWhiteList' ? why is it a std::vector ?

Comment: again, it does not make any sense to write a vector of points to an image.

Comment: Requirement: I need to remove white background from image "abc.png" and put the resultant image on another image "def.png", so was using vector<point> to remove white background, pls let know if you have any other approach.

Comment: Got the result.    here is codefor(int j=0; j<in.rows; ++j)
    for(int i=0; i<in.cols; ++i)
    {
        // if not black: add to the list
        if(in.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i) != cv::Vec3b(255,255,255))
        {
            nonWhiteList.push_back(cv::Point(i,j));
   BKGR.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i) = in.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i);
        }
    }

 cv::imwrite("newFinalImage.png", BKGR);

Answer (score 0):

```
 cv::Mat BKGR = imread("photo_booth_Cars.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR); //1529x736            
for(int j=0; j<in.rows; ++j) 


for(int i=0; i<in.cols; ++i)
{

    if(in.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i) != cv::Vec3b(255,255,255))
    {
BKGR.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i) = in.at<cv::Vec3b>(j,i);
    }
}

cv::imwrite("newFinalImage.png", BKGR);
```

Answer (score -1):

If the images are of same dimensionality than it makes sense else it is difficult to copy directly unless you know the 2 image camera parameters. However, you may use Interpolation to get the two images to same size.

If the images are same size, than why do you need to create a std::vector than copy it to another cv::Mat. You can achieve this in the same loop without extra computation overhead. Just simple as filling an array. However your question is ambiguous.

Comment: images are different size